Why does the Hagada say "אחד"?
By the 4 sons - the Hagada says  אחד חכם ואחד רשע ואחד תם...
Why? It should just say חכם ורשע ותם ושאינו יודע לשאול!?!

That wouldn't work grammatically.

@shmosel - why not?

@CuriousYid - that is more what I was reffering to

In Yerushalmi in Pesachim 10:4 it says, כְּנֶגֶד אַרְבָּעָה בָּנִים דִּיבְּרָה תוֹרָה. בֶּן חָכָם בֶּן רָשָׁע בֶּן טִיפֵּשׁ בֶּן שֶׁאֵינוֹ יוֹדֵעַ לִשְׁאָל, so we have the same style there also just with the word בֶּן

@AvishaiTebeka - correct, but we still have the same question!

After your edit, this question makes infinitely more sense. Hopefully you will get those -1s back! Here's a +1 from me. @CuriousYid your comment no longer applies, I strongly recommend deleting it

Found a possible answer in the Shibulei Haleket here:

מילתא באנפי נפשה היא ואינו סמוך על מה שאומר למעלה ופירושו מצות ההגדה
היא כתובה בארבעה מקומות ולפי המקראות הכתובים אנו למידין שכנגד ארבעה
בנים דברה תורה כדמפרש ואזיל
"This part (כְּנֶגֶד אַרְבָּעָה בָנִים) is a thing on its own and is
not connected to the above, and the explanation is that the mitzvah of
Haggadah is mentioned 4 times according to the pesukim we learn, that
the Torah speaks corresponding to four sons as it mentions those
pesukim."

I want to expand and explain this: Since he says that the Torah is speaking corresponding to four sons, which means that there really is one mitzvah of saying the Haggadah (which is mentioned 4 times), that translates into relaying information in four ways (four sons rasha, chacham, etc), and we respond to each child in their own way using the pesukim in the haggdah.
To show this, the Haggdah chose the word אחד, as each person is different, unique, special and is being addressed by different pesukim; it's a completely different haggadah/limud for each and every one of the 4 sons!
This concept of speaking to people differently according to their nature is sourced in many places including Mishlei 22:6 (חֲנֹךְ לַנַּעַר עַל־פִּי דַרְכּוֹ), Brachot 58b (שֶׁאֵין דַּעְתָּם דּוֹמָה זֶה לָזֶה, וְאֵין פַּרְצוּפֵיהֶן דּוֹמִים זֶה לָזֶה- meaning everyone is different and need to be taught in their way), and the Torah recognizes this and therefore Chazal made a model of this idea to address each person and teach him/her the story of yetziat mitzraim in his/her particular way and used the word אחד to signify that.

yes! amazing! thank you so much (shift+1)

Happy you like it

@AvishaiTebeka do note that there is a quote block ("blockquote") button in the editor (or CTRL+Q), which you can apply to highlighted text to turn it into a quote, and it will make your answers more readable. I have edited your answer. You don't need to add a > every line mind you, you can just do it at the beginning of each paragraph, with a lone > in between paragraphs

@Rabbi Kaii, thanks for letting me know

@AvishaiTebeka thanks for your gracious acceptance of advice and your gratitude. It is refreshing

For a deeper explanation: The Rebbe Rayatz (Likutei Diborim 3; 844) explains this to mean that both the chochom and the rasha have an "echad". It's just that the rasha's echad is concealed and must be revealed. The Rebbe (Likutei Sichos 1; 249) explains this to refer to the level of chochmah within every Jew (of the 10 bechinos one's soul is made of). The Tanya (chapters 18-19) explains that this bechina of chochma is the innate level in every Jew that is connected and strives to re-unite with Hashem echad.

Welcome to MiYodeya Dovid and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!
